# Rolling mean over one axis in 3D-array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Is there a simple way to calculate the rolling mean over one axis in a 3D-array? Let's say I have an array with x,y and time axis and I want the rolling mean over the time axis for all x and y.
For 1D-arrays I use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd 

rolling_array = pd.Series(array).rolling(window=window).mean()
```

But this does not work for multidimensional data.

EDIT:

My array looks like this:

```
import numpy as np 

array = np.random.rand(100,100,200)
```

And I want the rolling mean over `axis = 2`

Comment: @Divakar Is ```np.mean``` capable of a rolling window?

Comment: Oh its not. I missed that.

Comment: How about uniform filter - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter1d.html?

Comment: @HansHirse I have a numpy 3D-array with precipitation values for every x and y coordinate and every time step - so it is really a 3D-array.

Comment: pandas Series are one dimensional. Use DataFrame instead

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work" mean. Do you get an error? What is the expected result and what do you get?

Comment: @NikolayManolov Divakar already solved my problem.

Comment: I noticed, that's great, but it would still be nice to explain in what way it doesn't work. This would be helpful to other's who are looking for a solution to the same or similar problem

Comment: @NikolayManolov The rolling mean function in pandas does not work for multidimensional arrays and I couldn't see how to solve it.

Comment: It works for two dimensions, but I see this is not your use-case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`uniform_filter1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter1d.html) that accepts `axis` arg and we will make it generic to accept any n-dim array along a generic axis -

```
from scipy.ndimage import uniform_filter1d

def rolling_mean_along_axis(a, W, axis=-1):
    # a : Input ndarray
    # W : Window size
    # axis : Axis along which we will apply rolling/sliding mean
    hW = W//2
    L = a.shape[axis]-W+1   
    indexer = [slice(None) for _ in range(a.ndim)]
    indexer[axis] = slice(hW,hW+L)
    return uniform_filter1d(a,W,axis=axis)[tuple(indexer)]
```

Sample run to verify shapes :

```
In [70]: a = np.random.rand(10,10,10)

In [72]: rolling_mean_along_axis(a, W=5, axis=0).shape
Out[72]: (6, 10, 10)

In [73]: rolling_mean_along_axis(a, W=5, axis=1).shape
Out[73]: (10, 6, 10)

In [74]: rolling_mean_along_axis(a, W=5, axis=2).shape
Out[74]: (10, 10, 6)
```